# How can i get data from Google App engine Datastore after deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I made a web app using app engine and gwt. In this app i am also using google datastore. Before i deployed my application i had access to my datastore. I stored some data and then i was able to show them on my browser. I just deployed my application in App Engine and i can't show them anymore... More specific  i have a menu and a table. When i choose something from the menu i make a rpc to get the right data from my datastore and then i show them on the table in my webpage. Before i deploy my app this was working fine. Now when i go to my web page which is running on cloud and click something on the menu i get an empty table.How can i fix this? I read something about the credentials but it wasn't very helpful. Can someone explain what should i do?When i run the program in my console it works.
This is the code i am using to get the data.

```
DatastoreService ds= DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    Query q=new Query(s);
    PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(q);
    for (Entity entity : pq.asIterable()) {

        table.add(entity.getProperty("Name);
    }return table;
```

Comment: did you get any exception? error? what do you mean by "_can't show_"?

Comment: Well i have a menu and a table. When i choose something from the menu i make a rpc to get the right data from my datastore and then i show them on the table in my webpage. Before i deploy my app this was working fine. Now when i go to my web page which is running on cloud and click something on the menu i get an empty table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you were developing the code, you were most likely using a local datastore, after deploying you are now using the actual datastore linked to your project.(If I have understood your question correctly, you expect your local data to appear after deployment, this will not happen as loacal datastore is not synced with actual datastore.) To upload or download intial data, you could either create a script/handler on you server side which will either read from csv or a better way is to [enable remote api](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi)

Remote api is basically a web based datastore access mechanism. You can now bulk insert data either using a python script or even write code in java which can be run locally on your local machine but will basically affect datastore in cloud (through internal webservice).

To enable remote api

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>Remote API Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.apphosting.utils.remoteapi.RemoteApiServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RemoteApiServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/remote_api</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in python you could write a bulk insert script like this

```
sys.path.append('/usr/local/google_appengine/')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/google_appengine/lib')
sys.path.append('/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib/')
sys.path.append(
    os.path.abspath(
        os.path.dirname(
            os.path.realpath(__file__))))
if 'google' in sys.modules:
    del sys.modules['google']

from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from db import Post
import csv



 app_id = 'blah'
 host = '%s.appspot.com' % app_id
 remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth(host, '/_ah/remote_api', True)
```

after the above line

```
print MyRemoteEntity.query().count()
```

for java read [this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zOzZ7VsQ7skC&pg=PA152&lpg=PA152&dq=RemoteApiOptions%20options%20%3D%20new%20RemoteApiOptions()&source=bl&ots=KZkqDdr07v&sig=p0gVLb7y9dTgEA_PlbBcjET9qhc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4qfLt4sPLAhUJuRQKHQ33D0kQ6AEILjAE#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: How do i enable remote api? Should i write some code on the class where i used to do the connection with my datastore?

Comment: I'm using java! Thank's a lot!!

Comment: One last thing just to be sure... Should i put the remote api inside the class which i use to store my data? And after the installation of the api should i run this class again to store the data in the cloud datastore?

Answer (score 1):

The data you created locally won't be deployed to GAE. If there wasn't much of it that you added locally - simply re-create it again on the deployed version the way you did it locally and keep developing with this fact in mind (that local data won't be deployed). If there was a lot of data you created locally though - you might need to follow the suggestion here to use the remote api to sync the two.